# Is it possible to override a hardcoded transaction timeout in configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope

At one point in our software, a hardcoded (meaning in C# code in a Workflow) transactiontimeout has been implemented in a transactionscope.
Is there any way to override (increase!) the setting **without** changing the code?

.Net 3.5

WF 3.5

I know there are settings for default and max transaction timeouts, but sadly they won't help here.

Comment: as far as a know, your code settings takes priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to use settings from configuration file. Afterwards, just change the value in config file and code will automatically read the new value.

Comment: Hi jags. If I modify the code and not set any value I can set it from app.config.
But as written, I really am searching for a way to do this now without changing code.

Comment: You should modify the code to set the value using ConfigurationManager class's AppSettings property.

Comment: I don't want to change the code. That's explicitly part of the problem and my question.

Comment: This would require changing the code only once, thereafter the code will not need to be changed to change the timeout value. However if for some reason, if you are unable to change the code, then I do not think there is a way to override the hardcoded value.

Comment: I've had the same issue myself and the simple answer is - you can't. You need to provide a build which uses a dynamic value specified in the config, otherwise you are stuck!